# Count number of elements in numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

How do I count the number of elements of each datapoint in a ndarray?

What I want to do is to run a OneHotEncoder on all the values that are present at least N times in my ndarray.

I also want to replace all the values that appears less than N times with another element that it doesn't appear in the array (let's call it new_value).

So for example I have :

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[2], [2,3], [3,34]],
              [[3], [4,5], [3,34]],
              [[3], [2,3], [3,4] ]]])
```

with threshold N=2  I want something like:

```
b = [OneHotEncoder(a[:,[i]])[0] if count(a[:,[i]])>2 
else OneHotEncoder(new_value) for i in range(a.shape(1)]
```

So only to understand the substitutions that I want, not considering the onehotencoder and using new_value=10 my array should  look like:

```
a = np.array([[[10], [2,3], [3,34]],
                [[3], [10], [3,34]],
                [[3], [2,3], [10] ]]])
```

Comment: Do you really need to have arrays of lists? This will cripple numpy very seriously. A lot of operations (like comparisons for equality) that will normally be handled by fast C function calls will now have to be relayed to expensive Python calls. @Ophion's code solves your problem as stated, but you should seriously consider whether a different approach (an array of floats with `np.nan`s, or an array of ints with e.g. -1 denoting missing values) that lets you exploit numpy's capabilities to the fullest is not a better option.

Comment: the structure is like that to consider various combinatinon of bigrams /trigrams
if I had the entry [3,2,1] then i want to consider the unigrams [3],[2],[1] but also the bigrams [3,2] and [2,1] so the entry will become [ [3],[2],[1],[3,2],[2,1] ]

I didn't wrote the code and I didnt' want to modify it much cause it's quite complex,I was just interested to see if the performance (in terms of corrected predictions) will increase  filtering the rare events and put them all in the same category.

but probably you are rigth, I should speed it up cause I'm loosing time waiting anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like this?

First count the number of unqiue elements in an array:

```
>>> a=np.random.randint(0,5,(3,3))
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 4],
       [0, 2, 4],
       [2, 4, 0]])
>>> ua,uind=np.unique(a,return_inverse=True)
>>> count=np.bincount(uind)
>>> ua
array([0, 1, 2, 4]) 
>>> count
array([3, 1, 2, 3])
```

From the `ua` and `count` arrays it shows that 0 shows up 3 times, 1 shows up 1 time, and so on.

```
import numpy as np

def mask_fewest(arr,thresh,replace):
    ua,uind=np.unique(arr,return_inverse=True)
    count=np.bincount(uind)
    #Here ua has all of the unique elements, count will have the number of times 
    #each appears.


    #@Jamie's suggestion to make the rep_mask faster.
    rep_mask = np.in1d(uind, np.where(count < thresh))
    #Find which elements do not appear at least `thresh` times and create a mask

    arr.flat[rep_mask]=replace 
    #Replace elements based on above mask.

    return arr


>>> a=np.random.randint(2,8,(4,4))
[[6 7 7 3]
 [7 5 4 3]
 [3 5 2 3]
 [3 3 7 7]]


>>> mask_fewest(a,5,50)
[[10  7  7  3]
 [ 7  5 10  3]
 [ 3  5 10  3]
 [ 3  3  7  7]]
```

For the above example: Let me know if you intended a 2D array or 3D array.

```
>>> a
[[[2] [2, 3] [3, 34]]
 [[3] [4, 5] [3, 34]]
 [[3] [2, 3] [3, 4]]]


>>> mask_fewest(a,2,10)
[[10 [2, 3] [3, 34]]
 [[3] 10 [3, 34]]
 [[3] [2, 3] 10]]
```

Comment: thanks a lot but when I wrote [3,4] I actually meant an array with two  elements, and  yes my dataset will be really large

Comment: +1 If I had any money I'd bet it on some time soon there being a `np.count_unique` function that calls `np.bincount` on the indices returned by `np.unique` with `return_inverse=True`, it's a construct I find myself typing over and over again. As a potential improvement, I was a little troubled by the 2D array you are building and collapsing to compute the mask: that kind of trickery usually scales very badly. I just figured out that it is much faster for large datasets, and only slightly slower for really small ones, to do: `rep_mask = np.in1d(a, ua[count < thresh])`.

Comment: @Jaime: Thank you for the comments, I had forgotten about `np.in1d`. I kept looking up `np.intersect1d` and knew I was missing something. As a side note I think this will be hard to modify to actually answer the OP's question, since he needs an `object array`- should it be deleted?

Comment: I think the approach is the right one, and it can be made to work with minor changes: with the OP's test data it has trouble with `np.in1d` as I suggested, it probably worked with your earlier version, but comparing indices instead of the actual objects works just fine: `rep_mask = np.in1d(uind, np.where(count < thresh))`.

Comment: Ah very interesting, didnt think that would work. I appreciate the help on this question.

Comment: thanks Jaime adn Ophion  for your contribution, I'll try to play around with your solutinons.

Maybe it's not the right approach, I will try some "dirty" solution as well

cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much it worked perfectly! Just future reference I think you should put 
ua,uind=np.unique(arr,return_inverse=True)
instead of: 
ua,uind=np.unique(a,return_inverse=True). But thanks a lot it really helps me!